How to fix a smooth scrolling behavior bug after the initial rendering of the page?
After the page has been loaded or the user has updated it, the hyperlink or any other tags that are able to link, the site will not scroll smoothly to the desired place(lower than need).
So how do I fix this so that even after rendering the page everything works fine?
"use client";

import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-scroll";

interface ButtonNavigationProps {
  navigateTo: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const ButtonNavigation: React.FC<ButtonNavigationProps> = ({
  navigateTo,
  children,
}) => {
  return (
    <Link
      smooth={true}
      spy={true}
      isDynamic={true}
      to={navigateTo}
      offset={-130}
      duration={650}
      className="flex items-center gap-x-2 px-8 py-3"
    >
      {children}
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        height="24"
        viewBox="0 -960 960 960"
        width="24"
        fill="currentColor"
      >
        <path d="m560-240-56-58 142-142H160v-80h486L504-662l56-58 240 240-240 240Z" />
      </svg>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default ButtonNavigation;

Currently, there are two cases after which such a scrolling bug does not occur:

Only after the user scrolls through the site independently or uses the link navigation for the second time (the first time the navigation did not scroll to the right place on the page), then all the navigation works fine.

If the link doesn't have smooth behavior then everything will work fine from the first page rendering, but since I care about smooth behavior, I can't find any other options to replace it.


I understand that this is not normal behavior and is most likely a smooth scrolling bug. I also checked whether the page was fully loaded so that I could scroll - it didn't help.

"use client";

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-scroll";

interface ButtonNavigationProps {
  navigateTo: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const ButtonNavigation: React.FC<ButtonNavigationProps> = ({
  navigateTo,
  children,
}) => {
  // State to track whether the page is fully loaded
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Function to set the state when the page is fully loaded
    const handleLoad = () => {
      setIsLoaded(true);
    };

    // Check if the page has already loaded
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
      setIsLoaded(true); // Set to true immediately if the page is fully loaded
    } else {
      // If the page is not yet loaded, add an event listener to trigger once it finishes loading
      window.addEventListener("load", handleLoad);
    }

    // Cleanup event listener when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("load", handleLoad);
    };
  }, []); // Empty dependency array means this runs once when the component mounts

  return (
    <Link
      smooth={true}
      spy={true}
      isDynamic={true}
      to={navigateTo}
      offset={-130}
      duration={650}
      className="flex items-center gap-x-2 px-8 py-3"
      isDisabled={!isLoaded} // Disable smooth scrolling until the page is fully loaded
    >
      {children}
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        height="24"
        viewBox="0 -960 960 960"
        width="24"
        fill="currentColor"
      >
        <path d="m560-240-56-58 142-142H160v-80h486L504-662l56-58 240 240-240 240Z" />
      </svg>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default ButtonNavigation;


I really appreciate your answer! Checked your code - didn't help me. So I think the reason is something else
